# Tesseract installation error in "Make" file

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using following system
    * **Tesseract Version**: 4.0.0-324-gb67f
    * **Platform**: Ubuntu16.04 64-bit
I want to retrain tesseract, I am referring to Googles documentation at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/INSTALL. Here are the steps that I am following

```
1. git pull https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract.git

2. cd tesseract/

3. ./autogen.sh

4. ./configure

5. make

6. make check
```

After doing make check I am observing this error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ajinkya/Documents/tesseract/doc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'check'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ajinkya/Documents/tesseract/doc'
Making check in unittest
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ajinkya/Documents/tesseract/unittest'
make  libgtest.la libgtest_main.la libgmock.la libgmock_main.la libabseil.la apiexample_test applybox_test baseapi_test bitvector_test cleanapi_test colpartition_test dawg_test denorm_test fileio_test heap_test imagedata_test indexmapbidi_test intfeaturemap_test intsimdmatrix_test lang_model_test layout_test linlsq_test loadlang_test mastertrainer_test matrix_test nthitem_test osd_test paragraphs_test progress_test qrsequence_test recodebeam_test rect_test resultiterator_test shapetable_test stats_test stringrenderer_test tablefind_test tablerecog_test tabvector_test tfile_test commandlineflags_test lstm_recode_test lstm_squashed_test lstm_test lstmtrainer_test unichar_test unicharcompress_test unicharset_test validate_grapheme_test validate_indic_test validate_khmer_test validate_myanmar_test validator_test
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ajinkya/Documents/tesseract/unittest'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc', needed by '../googletest/googletest/src/libgtest_la-gtest-all.lo'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ajinkya/Documents/tesseract/unittest'
Makefile:2207: recipe for target 'check-am' failed
make[1]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ajinkya/Documents/tesseract/unittest'
Makefile:495: recipe for target 'check-recursive' failed
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Why do you say "Googles documentation" where it is documentation whose copyright is held, in fact, by the Free Software Foundation?

Answer (score 1):

You run version from git you have to follow https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/INSTALL.GIT.md instruction.

Also why are you running `make check`? Do you understand what are you doing? Even instruction you posted above marks it as **optional**...